# Differential voltage measurement on shunt resistor

Tags: current, differential, probe, monitor

I trying to build a simple differential measurement circuit to feed a analog to digital chip to monitor current consumption of a board with an Arduino. So I decided to go with a "traditional" differential amplifier with op-amp in front to get a nice high impedance for this improvise differential probe. Here's a simple schematic of my circuit: (Op-amp have 12v supply)

[image: schematic]

To my surprise, the reading on the 5 ohm shunt resistor is way off the real reading (measure with a multimeter). Instead of having 2.02V which correspond to a 404mA consumption (which is what is expected), I got 43mV!? I used this probe (pin 3 & 5) to check voltage around others components on my board and the reading are correct. But on the shunt R1, it's completely off. I tough that since it's a really low resistance that my high-impedance will be ok be it seems not. I look around on the net and the solution seems to go with this approach but that's not working for me right now... Any suggestion?

Comment: You're powering the TLC272s off the same 12V rail? If so you are violating the common mode input range for IC1A and IC1B -- their inputs need to be about 1V below the positive rail, according to the [datasheet](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com%2Flitv%2Fslos091e&ei=4omhVYzRNpW3oQSop5r4BQ&usg=AFQjCNEhdWK5z4q097l-q87Pti6-Do6Q9g&sig2=a8az62G7rAas6yzwpSyekw&bvm=bv.97653015,d.aWw).

Comment: Even worse, you may be powering the 272 from the +5 line, in which case you're lucky the chip is still working - if it is still working.

Comment: @Null, which spec are you talking about? Page 4 : Differential input voltage, VID = +- VDD and Input voltage range, Vi is -0.3 to VDD. ?? Anyway, I made a test and and 2 x 2 diode in series to drop the voltage and it's the same.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast My question say : Op-amp have 12v supply. ??

Comment: \$V_{\text{ICR}}\$, p. 6. With a 10V supply the common mode input range is up to 9V, so you need about 1V of headroom.

Comment: @SteveS. - My apologies. I missed that.

Comment: @Null, after reading more about Vicm (http://www.planetanalog.com/document.asp?doc_id=528175) and lower the input voltage of pin 3 & 5 and still stuck with a 38mV reading...

Comment: How did you lower the input voltages? Also, what are all the voltages at the op amp inputs and outputs? And are you getting the correct 5V at the output of IC2?

Comment: @Null, see edited answer. Voltage at input are in the range of 11.95 to 10.9 (2V drop). 7805 happily output 5.00v. I switch to a TLC271 on the differential part because I can precisely adjust (zeroing) input offset voltage.

Comment: If you solved your problem, please post the solution as an answer, not as part of the question.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I end up doing. And it work. Thx to Null for pointing in the right direction about Vicm and Chu for the swap on R1.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The output voltage (to ADC) is trying to go negative, since the left side of \$R_1\$ is more positive than the right side. Try reversing the connections to \$R_1\$

Comment: Good point! Probably changing that + lower voltage input did solve the case. So it a 50/50 answer ;-)